# javascript date/time is not a number when I expand object

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I have an AngularJS app that I'm working on and I have an object that contains dates. I added a console.log to my application so I can see what the data looks like just before I save it. I see the following, which is what I expect (Note: I am based in Australia):
[image]

I have a tester that is testing our application, he is based in Malaysia, this is what he is getting. Can anyone explain wht the start and end times are showing as NaN?
[image]

Comment: I don't think anyone can explain that without seeing the relevant code, no.

Comment: How do you create the Date? How do you assign values to *end_time* and *start_time*? Where is the code?